# Items not rendering in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and Material-UI. I am not getting any errors but the component with the info is not displaying anything

```
import React from "react";
import { RouteHandler } from "react-router";
import MainMenu from "components/MainMenu";
import _ from "lodash";
import mui, { RaisedButton, AppBar,  FlatButton, Toolbar,
                            ToolbarGroup, DropDownMenu, ToolbarTitle, FontIcon,
                            DropDownIcon, ToolbarSeparator} from 'material-ui';

let ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager();

import styles from "./Application.css";

let filterOptions = [
  { payload: '1', text: 'All Broadcasts' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'All Voice' },
  { payload: '3', text: 'All Text' },
  { payload: '4', text: 'Complete Voice' },
  { payload: '5', text: 'Complete Text' },
  { payload: '6', text: 'Active Voice' },
  { payload: '7', text: 'Active Text' },
];
let iconMenuItems = [
  { payload: '1', text: 'Download' },
  { payload: '2', text: 'More Info' }
];

export default class Application extends React.Component {
  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
    };
  }

    static getProps(stores, params) {
        var transition = stores.Router.getItem("transition");
        return {
            loading: !!transition
        };
    }
    render() {
        var { loading } = this.props;
        return <div className={styles.this + (loading ? " " + styles.loading : "")}>
            <Toolbar>
              <ToolbarGroup key={0} float="left">
                <DropDownMenu menuItems={filterOptions} />
              </ToolbarGroup>
              <ToolbarGroup key={1} float="right">
                <ToolbarTitle text="Options" />
                <FontIcon className="mui-icon-sort" />
                <DropDownIcon iconClassName="icon-navigation-expand-more" menuItems={iconMenuItems} />
                <ToolbarSeparator/>
                <RaisedButton label="Create Broadcast" primary={true} />
              </ToolbarGroup>
            </Toolbar>
              <br />                
            <div className={styles.loadingElement}>loading...</div>
            <MainMenu />
            <RouteHandler />
        </div>;
    }
}

Application.contextTypes = {
    stores: React.PropTypes.object
};

Application.childContextTypes = {
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

`filterOptions` and `iconMenuItems` are not rendering, though the rest are OK.

Comment: The two components don't even get generated into DOM and the rest of the `Application` does?

Comment: Please share the contents of DropDownMenu and DropDownIcon components.

Comment: As he said, he uses [Material UI](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAAahUKEwi8gYinvP3GAhXDShQKHUMyDDc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmaterial-ui.com%2F&ei=zUW3VfzmOsOVUcPksLgD&usg=AFQjCNFIb8G1kDvwvXVKmxb4DoE8VIaDDw): [DropDownIcon](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/drop-down-icon.jsx), [DropDownMenu](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/drop-down-menu.jsx).

Comment: @jalooc yes, those 2 components are no generating anything in the DOM. The Docs for this library are very very bad.

Comment: I must admit you're right about the documentation, although the components' code is rather short and fairly easy to read - if you have any doubts I can recommend taking a look inside. As to the code you've posted, unfortunatelly I don't see anything wrong...

Comment: By the way, for managing style classes, like in the exterior 'div', I recommend you using [Classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames), as suggested by React itself - it gets less messy.

Comment: @jalooc yes, as I was unable to render anything in the DOM, I took I look at the component and how it was build, and was doing everything properly. It is very weird.